# Jenkins-pipeline different checkout on first build daily

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

i have to different checkout rules
one that cleans everything and take out a clean and fresh checkout and one that does a incremental update.

I want to runt the first one Only when it is the first run for the day, and the incremental on every other that day.

Any suggestions how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jenkins pipelines, you could write a file with current date. Say you first job is running and checks the file's content : if file content is yesterday date, then it is the first build of the day so you process you full clean step and write today's date, otherwise you just do your incremental update and do not re-write the file.

However, you should maybe reconsider your CI strategy as it is often good practice to have reproducible builds, where you can replay exactly the same steps all the times.

Answer (score 0):

The "Pre SCM BuildStep" plugin allows to add build steps that are executed prior to the checkout. This allows to clean the workspace before the update happens.

You might consider to add a specific checkout time (e.g. 02:00 AM) and add a Pre-SCM Build step that cleans the workspace if the current time is between 02:00 and 03:00. This way, you get a clean build every morning and every checkin just gives you a fast (update) build response.